# Raw SQL Queries Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Currently I have created a model called getData.php, which uses a raw query to pull information from the database and pass it back to the main controller.

**getData.php**

```
namespace Destination\AppBundle\Models;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class getData extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getInfo(){

            $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('select * cms_clients');
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            return $result;
    }

}
```

**Maincontroller.php**

```
namespace Destination\AppBundle\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; 
use Destination\InterfaceBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Destination\AppBundle\Models\getData;
class DefaultController extends  AbstractController


    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
    $fetchData = new getData;   

        $fetchData->getInfo();


        return $this->render('DestinationAppBundle:Default:app.html.twig');   

    }

]
```

But i keep getting the same error saying

> ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in
>   C:\Users\brent.french\Documents\www\clients\app\src\Destination\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
>   on line 33 and defined in
>   C:\Users\brent.french\Documents\www\clients\app\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php
>   line 67

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an EntityRepository, but you're not supposed to access the methods you define in the EntityRepository directly, like you're doing it here:

```
$fetchData = new getData;   
$fetchData->getInfo();
```

You have to access that method through whatever entitiy is the "parent" of "getData".

For example, if you have an Entity called Data:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="namespace\yourbundle\Entity\getData")
*/
class Data {
/** your setters and getters **/
}
```

Then you can access your getData methods in your controllers this way:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$getData =  $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Data')->getData();
```

make sure to include the path to your entity repository at the top of the controller:

```
use Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\GetData;
```

Otherwise, you may get an error (depending on your symfony version).

In your example, it seems like your namespace is called `Destination` and your bundle is called `AppBundle`,

then the `@ORM\Entity` annotation, should look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Destination\AppBundle\Model\getData")
 */
```

Read this section of the symfony2 docs, they elaborate more on this topic:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: But if the database has already been created, how can i setup my setters and getters?

Comment: All the tutorials i find are for setting a new database up but the problem is i need to use a per-existing database.

Comment: Setting up setters and getters is possible whether the database has been created already or not. Worst case scenario, you may need to run `php app/console --env=prod doctrine:schema:update --force` to update your schema. Open up the entity file that maps the table you want to select, and inside the `@ORM\Entity` annotation add the `repositoryClass` option. The value of `repositoryClass` should be the path to your class file (relative to the namespace).

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that your getData class extends EntityRepository which (as the error messages indicate) expects some arguments in it's constructor.

If you are determined to use raw queries then inject the connection into your getData class

```
class GetData
{
    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;

// In your controller
$getData = new GetData($this->getEntityManager()->getConnection());
```

You can go one step further and define GetData as a service:

```
cerad_app_cerad.persons.export_xml:
    class: Cerad\Bundle\AppCeradBundle\Services\Persons\Persons01ExportXML
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.dbal.default_connection'

// In your controller
$getData = $this->get('cerad_app_cerad.persons.export_xml');
```

By the way, the DBAL connection object has some nice convenience methods:

```
    $rows = $this->conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM cms');
```

Comment: The first answer you provided does not work, is there any real easy way to pull data from a database without using doctrine?

Comment: You can use PDO directly but unless you take the time to understand how php works, I'm afraid you might have trouble.  Lot's of issues with your question.